# animated movie about a man who falls in love with an alien who has no mouth

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

Looking for an animated movie that I watched parts of when I was a child, so it would have been from the mid 90's. Possibly may have been created in the early 80's.

Memory's a bit hazy because it was so long ago but it involved a man falling in love with a being (alien?) that had no mouth and a hole where its stomach was meant to be (I could just be imagining that last part) possibly they had a child together (again could be imagining that too)

I do remember there being a woman that got angry that he was more interested in the other species. Also could have been an adult animation because I do remember that I had been watching it late at night.

Answer (score 4):

It's a long shot, but it could be [*Aeon Flux*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86on_Flux).

It's a series, not a movie, with a very distinctive animation style and bizarre stories; it was produced and broadcast by MTV from 1991 to 1995, which fits in the timeframe you indicated.

In particular, what you remember seeing could be the last episode (S03E10 *"End Sinister"*, [Wikipedia summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_%C3%86on_Flux_episodes#ep10)):

- the *man* and the *angry woman* are Trevor Goodchild and Aeon Flux, main protagonists of the series and bound in a love/hate relationship
- the *alien* (which has no mouth and lacks most of the lower torso) is actually a mutated human

The whole series can be found on the [official site](http://www.mtv.com/shows/aeon-flux), but the episodes are only available to registered users of several TV providers.

Comment: Horrible-quality video of the [episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wwpIhsmzFlU) on YouTube, so that you can check if that's what you were looking for.